# css: specific action on links only when they're within a particular class

Tags: css

I'm having a hard time understanding how to do this simple task in CSS.

Here's the basic HTML code:

```
<div class="menu">
 <div class="menuItem uno"><a href="/one.php">1<span>One</span></a></div>
 <div class="menuItem dos"><a href="/two.php">2<span>Two</span></a></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to change the css formatting for `a:` (hyperlinks), but ONLY when they are inside of this `menu` class so that this:

```
a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

is bypassed.

I have a `.menu` in my css file:

```
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 15px;
  etc...
}
```

then after that I have

```
.menu a:active, a:hover, a:link, a:visited {
    outline: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

this does nothing to links inside of my `menu` class, but it is affecting hyperlinks outside of this `menu` div.  What am I doing wrong in my formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the entire selector each time.

```
.menu a:active,
.menu a:hover,
.menu a:link,
.menu a:visited {
    outline: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

If you were using a CSS preprocessor, like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), you could nest the selectors:

```
.menu {
    a:hover,
    a:link,
    a:active,
    a:visited {
        outline: 0;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to say:

```
.menu a:active, .menu a:hover, .menu a:link, .menu a:visited {
    outline: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Each selector in the comma-separated list stands on its own; `.menu` won't apply to everything in the line.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `.menu` in front of each anchor selector in the bottom CSS, the selector you're using right now targets `active` anchor tags only within the menu, but it targets the `hover`, `link` and `visited` ones anywhere within the page because you didn't provide the same specificity:

```
.menu a:active, .menu a:hover, .menu a:link, .menu a:visited {
    outline: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```